# view a PDF without downloading it

Tags: pdf, razor, asp.net-core

Now my controller returns the file in this way:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult document(int id)
{
      var byteArray = db.instances.Where(c => c.id == id).FirstOrDefault().document;    
      if (byteArray == null)
      {
            return null;
      }
      Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

      return File(stream, "application/pdf", "document.pdf");
}
```

Client:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("document", "Catalog", new { id = Model.id })" target="_blank">Open pdf</a>
```

I would like to view the PDF without downloading it, how can I do it?

Comment: Specifiying the filename parameter to `File` actually causes a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header to be set. This header actually forces download. The default behavior is to view inline. So, the key is to not specify the filename. However, bear in mind that viewing a PDF in browser is still conditional on the capabilities of the client's browser. If it doesn't support viewing PDFs natively or doesn't have a PDF-viewing plugin installed, then it will still prompt a download no matter what, and there's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append a header to your response saying it should display it instead of downloading

This way:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult document(int id)
{
      var byteArray = db.instances.Where(c => c.id == id).FirstOrDefault().document;    
      if (byteArray == null)
      {
            return null;
      }
      Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

      Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");
      return File(stream, "application/pdf", "document.pdf");
}
```

Comment: I solved by removing also "document.pdf" from return File